# How to update only a part of a json which is stored in a database with a "json path" list?

Tags: python, json, django

Let´s say we have a database and there is a json stored as a string which contains configurations.
In the application we want to update only a specific value and write then back the json as  a string to the database.

The HTTP request provides a "jsonPath" which reflects a path in the json file to navigate to the object we want to update. This parameter is supplied as a list.

An example for the path could be something like *['input', 'keyboard', 'language']* and the value we want to set is *'en'*

Here we load the configuration from the database which works so far:

```
if request.data['jsonPath']: 
    config =  json.loads(models.Config.objects.get(name__startswith='general').value
```

Then config is just a normal object now, which I can access with the dot notation like config.input.keyboard.language and it contains then the according part in json syntax.

I am able to read out the value of the field with the following syntax:

```
config[request.data['jsonPath'][0]][request.data['jsonPath'][1]][request.data['jsonPath'[3]]
```

But the number of parameters can vary and I want also to write it back into the config object, convert it back to a string and write it into the database.

I know it is not a nice thing but I would be interessted how it can be done like this

Comment: check your db/orm might support parts of json stored in db.

Comment: `config` will contain basic python objects like list, dict and string. You can't do `config.input.keyboard.language` to read it. It sounds like you want to update that value in `config` and then save the full `config` back to the database. There is is a risk that something else also wrote that same record and you'll overwrite that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for this:

```
functools.reduce(dict.get, path, data)
```

---

```
from functools import reduce

data = {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': {'foo': 'bar'}}}}
path = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

reduce(dict.get, path, data)["foo"] = baz
```

Result:

```
{'key1': {'key2': {'key3': {'foo': 'baz'}}}}
```

#### P.S

If the data type of `data` is something else you could possibly use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

Comment: thank you. functools.reduce worked for me. To make it possible with the path-list, I removed the last element from the list and passed it as the key argument for the dict ( "foo" in your example). Afterwards I converted back the dict into a Json (json.dumps) and wrote it back into the database

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a nested json object like this:

```
mydict = {
    'key1': {
        'key2': {
            'key3': {
                'foo': 'bar'
            },
        },
    },
}
```

And you have a "path" list like this:

```
path = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

You can traverse the path like this:

```
data = mydict
for key in path:
    data = data[key]
```

`data` will end up as the value of the last item in `path`, in this case the subdict `{'foo': 'bar'}`